# DB software for mac

Tags: database, macos

i'm looking for a DB software that can run on mac server and serve multiple clients , all users can update the DB. 
the DB will hold thousands of contacts with loads of different fields (same as mac contacts , personal, freelancers, clients, others),
i want to be able to categorize contacts(entries) under Clients, Personal, Staff, etc.
Be able to print lists - in any order. Eg. Print all Clients, sorted by company name. Print all Personal sorted by Last Name. (be able to sort and to print data by company name, first name, last name, other...).
Be able to transfer data to an excel spreadsheet easily.
Export/import to an excel spreadsheet.
Sort and view by different fields and Search for any field.

please recommend a good software that can do all that , on a mac network ( server is mac and clients are all macs)

thanks in advance , 
amitos80

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve what you want. A centralized database on the server is one answer, but not necessarily the only answer. Are any of your clients on MacBook/MacBookPro's, iPhones or iPads? Do they need access from outside the office?

Comment: i have 5 to 10 clients thatare all mini macs and iMacs , and i dont need to access it from outside the office ,(thanks)

Answer (score 2):

[Filemaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) is a widely used database application for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL? It can do all of what you've said.

Comment: i'm looking for a software that can be easily installed , manage and deploy - without the help of DB experts.  i mean a commercial solution that i can buy maybe.., (thanks)

Comment: MySQL is not hard to install, and it's better than pretty much all commercial products out there.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) ?

> Don’t be fooled by the installer size!
>   Firebird is a fully featured and
>   powerful RDBMS. It can handle
>   databases from just a few KB to many
>   Gigabytes with good performance and
>   almost free of maintenance!